# Laravel, paso de parámetros a través de controlador a vista con llamada Ajax

Tags: laravel, ajax

Tengo una vista principal que tiene:

```
<a href="{{ url('solicitudes/sol_solicitante') }}"   
class="{{ Request::is('solicitudes/sol_solicitante') ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link' }}">
    <p>Buzón De Solicitudes</p>
</a>
```

El web route tiene:

```
Route::get('solicitudes/sol_solicitante','SolicitudesController@sol_solicitante')->name('solicitudes.sol_solicitante');
Route::get('datatables/sol_solicitante','DatatableController@sol_solicitante')->name('datatable.sol_solicitante');
```

El controlador SolicitudesController tiene:

```
public function sol_solicitante(){

    return view('solicitante.solicitudes');

}
```

La vista llamada por el controlador anterior presenta una tabla de datos que se llena con una llamada Ajax:

```
<script>
    $('#buzonsolicitudes').DataTable({
        "ajax": "{{ route('datatable.sol_solicitante')}}",
        "columns":[
            {data:'id'},
            {data:'nombre'},
            {data:'estadologico'},
            {data:'btn'}
        ],
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar " + 
                            `<select class="custom-select" custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm>
                                <option value='10'>10</option>
                                <option value='25'>25</option>
                                <option value='50'>50</option>
                                <option value='100'>100</option>
                                <option value='-1'>Todos</option>
                            </select>` +
                            " registros por página",            
            "zeroRecords": "Nada encontrado - disculpa",
            "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "Ningún registro disponible",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
            'search':'Buscar',
            'paginate':{
                'next':'siguiente',
                'previous':'anterior'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

La ruta que invoca Ajax (route('datatable.sol_solicitante')) se encuentra en la info que está más arriba en el archivo route (web route)

El controlador datatable tiene:

```
    public function sol_solicitante(Request $request){
        
        $solicitudes=Solicitudes::select('id','nombre','estadologico')->where('ptoactual','=','1')->get();
        
        return datatables()->of($solicitudes)
        ->addColumn('btn','solicitante.btn')
        ->rawColumns(['btn'])        
        ->toJson();
    }
}
```

Este circuito lógico funciona bien, pero dado que esta llamada desde la vista principal la harán distintos roles de usuario, es que tendría que multiplicar lo anterior por cada rol de usuario que acceda a la vista principal al "Buzón De Solicitudes", qué básicamente se diferencian en que el contenido de la tabla que debe llenarse al final depende del campo "ptoactual". En el ejemplo que puse, llena la tabla con el ptoactual=1.

Lo que me he propuesto es que el circuito anterior sea uno solo y que desde la vista principal se pase un parámetro, en función del rol del usuario que hace clic al botón "Buzón De Solicitudes" y este llegue al único método que tendrá el controlador datatable y ahí dentro discrimine en función del parámetro que le llegue, qué registros debe cargar en la tabla (ptoactual=1, ptoactual=2, etc.)

Lo primero que he hecho es modificar en la vista principal, en el botón "Buzón De Solicitudes":

```
<a href="{{ url('solicitudes/sol_solicitante',['param' => '1']) }}"   
class="{{ Request::is('solicitudes/sol_solicitante') ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link' }}">
    <p>Buzón De Solicitudes</p>
</a>
```

El archivo de ruta lo modifiqué así:

```
Route::get('solicitudes/sol_solicitante/{param}','SolicitudesController@sol_solicitante')->name('solicitudes.sol_solicitante');
```

En el controlador de solicitudes, modifiqué así:

```
public function sol_solicitante(Request $request, $param){

    \Log::info('Ingresó al controlador de solicitudes'); 
    \Log::info($param);   
    
    return view('solicitante.solicitudes', ['param'=>$param]);

}
```

Le puse esos LOG para ver si llegaban los datos al controlador. Sí llegan:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El controlador invoca la vista solicitudes, donde se hace la llamada Ajax, allí modifiqué así (realmente no estoy seguro si se puede hacer así):

```
<script>
    $param={{'param'}}
    $('#buzonsolicitudes').DataTable({
        "ajax": "{{ route('datatable.sol_solicitante',['param' => $param])}}",
        "columns":[
            {data:'id'},
            {data:'nombre'},
            {data:'estadologico'},
            {data:'btn'}
        ],
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar " + 
                            `<select class="custom-select" custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm>
                                <option value='10'>10</option>
                                <option value='25'>25</option>
                                <option value='50'>50</option>
                                <option value='100'>100</option>
                                <option value='-1'>Todos</option>
                            </select>` +
                            " registros por página",            
            "zeroRecords": "Nada encontrado - disculpa",
            "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "Ningún registro disponible",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
            'search':'Buscar',
            'paginate':{
                'next':'siguiente',
                'previous':'anterior'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

No estoy seguro que se pueda recibir así el parámetro en la vista, dentro de la seccion SCRIPT.

En el archivo de rutas, hice la siguiente modificación:

```
Route::get('datatables/sol_solicitante/{param}','DatatableController@sol_solicitante')->name('datatable.sol_solicitante');
```

En el controlador datatable hice así:

```
public function sol_solicitante(Request $request, $param){
    
    $solicitudes=Solicitudes::select('id','nombre','estadologico')->where('ptoactual','=',$param)->get();
    
    return datatables()->of($solicitudes)
    ->addColumn('btn','solicitante.btn')
    ->rawColumns(['btn'])        
    ->toJson();
}
```

Al ejecutar, en la url de direcciones se genera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la consola arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me parece que el error está en la forma de recibir el parametro en la vista y la forma como se le pasa a la ruta del datatable.

Agradezco cualquier comentario que ayude a la solución.

Sólo para validar que el problema está en el paso del parámetro desde el controlador de solicitudes hacia la vista solicitudes y/o como acceder a dicho parámetro en la vista solicitud, puse el parámetro como valor en la vista solicitud, en la llamada Ajax:

```
<script>                
    $('#buzonsolicitudes').DataTable({
        "ajax": "{{ route('datatable.sol_solicitante',['param' => '1'])}}",
        "columns":[
            {data:'id'},
            {data:'nombre'},
            {data:'estadologico'},
            {data:'btn'}
        ],
```

La secuencia funciona correctamente. Con eso confirmo en que el problema se resume a cómo acceder en la vista solicitudes, al parámetro que envía el controlador de solicitudes, dado que debe acceder dentro de un

.  Si no fuera ahí, podría acceder como {{param}}.